# I am trying to return 3 values (State, Size, Department) but it only works if state is 1 word "Pennsylvania"

Tags: python, if-statement, strsplit

I am trying to return 3 values (State, Size, Department). You will see in the below code it works if the state is 1 word "Pennsylvania" but not if it is 2 words "New York".  You can comment out New York and un-comment PA to see it work.  I tried to use an if-else with a string split.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('## EVENT')
    print(event)
    #salesoutput=event['Details']['ContactData']['Attributes'].get('salesoutput',"Not Available")
    salesoutput= "New York 15 Nuts"
    #salesoutput= "Pennsylvania 15 Nuts"

    if  len(salesoutput.split()) > 3:
        prestate1 = salesoutput.split(' ')[0]
        prestate2 = salesoutput.split(' ')[1]
        State = prestate1 + " " + prestate2
        Size = salesoutput.split(' ')[2]
        Department = salesoutput.split(' ')[3]    
#        print("State:",State,"\nDistrict Size:",Size,"\nDepartment:",Department)
    
    else:
        State = salesoutput.split(' ')[0]
        Size = salesoutput.split(' ')[1]
        Department = salesoutput.split(' ')[2]    
#        print("State:",State,"\nDistrict Size:",Size,"\nDepartment:",Department)
    
def describe(Response):
    return State(Response), District(Response), Size(Response)
```

Comment: Can the department also be more than 1 word?

Answer (score 1):

If you're reasonably certain of the input format, why not just use regular expressions?

```
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    salesoutput= "New York 15 Nuts"
    pattern = re.compile(r'([\w\s]+)\s(\d{1,})\s([\w\s]+)')
    result = pattern.search(salesoutput)
    State, Size, Department = result.groups()        
    
    print("State:",State,"\nDistrict Size:",Size,"\nDepartment:",Department)    
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        "State":State,
        "Size":Size,
        "Department": Department
    }
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/DeadLumberingDataset-1#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = "New York 15 Nuts"
s2 = "Pennsylvania 15 Nuts"
for s in [s1, s2]:
    *State, Size, Department = s.split(" ")
    print("State:"," ".join(State),"\nDistrict Size:",Size,"\nDepartment:",Department)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `rsplit` with `maxsplit`:

```
>>> s = "New York 15 Nuts"
>>> s.rsplit(maxsplit=2)
['New York', '15', 'Nuts']

>>> s = "Pennsylvania 15 Nuts"
>>> s.rsplit(maxsplit=2)
['Pennsylvania', '15', 'Nuts']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the department is always one word, you can determine what to do depending on the length of the split array.

This solution is a quick fix.

The more optimal solution would be to separate the data by commas (if you have access to that data), and use salesoutput.split(',').

Note: I would split the array only once so that you are not creating multiple copies of the same split array, to save time and space.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('## EVENT')
    print(event)
    #salesoutput=event['Details']['ContactData']['Attributes'].get('salesoutput',"Not Available")
    salesoutput= "New York 15 Nuts"
    #salesoutput= "Pennsylvania 15 Nuts"
    
    sales = salesoutput.split(' ')
    if len(sales) == 3:
        State = sales[0]
        Size = sales[1]
        Department = sales[2]
    elif len(sales) == 4:
        State = sales[0] + " " + sales[1]
        Size = sales[2]
        Department = sales[3]
        
    print("State:",State,"\nDistrict Size:",Size,"\nDepartment:",Department)    
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        "State":State,
        "Size":Size,
        "Department": Department
        #"Email":response["Item"]["Email"]
        #'statusCode': 200,
        #'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Repl.it

Thank You That did it just had to adjust for json input.  This just shows my inexperience with Python...

```
import json
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    salesoutput=event['Details']['ContactData']['Attributes'].get('salesoutput',"Not Available")
    pattern = re.compile(r'([\w\s]+)\s(\d{1,})\s([\w\s]+)')
    result = pattern.search(salesoutput)
    State, Size, Department = result.groups()        
    
    print("State:",State,"\nDistrict Size:",Size,"\nDepartment:",Department)    
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        "State":State,
        "Size":Size,
        "Department": Department
    }
```